# user = discord.utils.get(client.users, name="name", discriminator="0000") comes back with none

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

So i want to be able to mention a user when I input there name and discriminator but I cant get it to work as it keeps return `none`

```
import discord

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

client = discord.Client(token=config.TOKEN, intents=intents)

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.content == "$test"
     user = discord.utils.get(client.users, name="killogee", discriminator="0141")
     print(user)
```

I've also tried:
`user = message.guild.get_member_named("Killogee")` 
but everytime comes back with `none`

Comment: Hello Killogee! I just tested this piece of code and it had [worked](https://imgur.com/a/csDbOA6), are you sure that you have written the correct name and discriminator? This function is case-sensitive, and the bot cannot find a user that matches exactly it will always return `None`. If you have access to the [user's id](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/206346498-Where-can-I-find-my-User-Server-Message-ID-) you could also use an alternative, such as [`client.get_user`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=get_user#discord.Client.get_user)

Comment: @bagle yeah i can do Client.get_user but I want to use the feature of putting in the name manually since I have a txt file with names and I want to grab the names and then be able to ping them. when I print client.users it comes back with [] is it meant to be like that?

Answer (score 0):

Set out your txt file like this:

```
user1#8583
user2#0637
user3#9729
```

Then just use this

```
f = open('names.txt','r').splitlines() # Opens the text file and turns it into a list
for i in f: # Iterate through that list
    i = i.split('#') # Split the line in two via the hashtag
    user = discord.utils.get(client.users, name=i[0], discriminator=i[1])
    # i[0] is the name, such as user1 and i[1] is the discriminator after the hashtag
    print(user)
```

It should work, so make sure that your names are correct and up to date